# wordpress css link broken after migrate to localhost

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I take backup from live wordpress site then try to run at localhost

1. import database
2. create folder web and paste all backup code
3. change database name n other stuff from config.php file

but site look like

[image]

i use these two line to avoid redirection to live site url 
its work but not for all url

```
define('WP_HOME','localhost/web/');
define('WP_SITEURL','localhost/web/');
```

below links broken....please give solution

[image]

primarily twentyeleven theme css link broken

Comment: updated the permalink in settings menu in admin panel?

Comment: Follow these step:
1-remove these line from config file: define('WP_HOME','localhost/web/');
define('WP_SITEURL','localhost/web/');
2- export file from live server before importing database file in your local open the exported file in noteped plus or sublime , then find site url and replace all instance of that url with http //localhost/web and then import it

Answer (score 0):

To avoid most of the issues, I would recommend to set up a fresh local version of WordPress and than import theme and content.

Maybe you have to change some setting in the database to adjust this to your local environment.